# DropDownList value and text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using jquery to populate a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('/GetFoo', function (result) {
        var ddl = $('#foo');
        ddl.empty();
        $(result).each(function () {
            $(document.createElement('option'))
                .attr('value', this.Id)
                .text(this.Text)
                .appendTo(ddl);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the controller action that return the JSON used in that process:

```
public ActionResult GetFoo()
{
    ViewBag.IdTable = new SelectList(db.Table, "IdTable", "Description");
        return Json(ViewBag.IdTable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And here's how my dropdown list goes into my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdTable,Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Loading Values --", new { id = "foo" })
```

To clarify more what I'm doing, I want to show the Description in the select list options instead of the IdTable.

Everything works just fine until the moment I validate my dropdown list choice. In fact, it gives the following error:

> The value [Choice] is not valid for IdTable.

So I guess the values of the select list options are set to the Description field, rather than the Id field.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult GetFoo()
{
    return Json(db.Table.Select(x=> new { Id = x.IdTable, Text = x.Description}), 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Or** in your JS change

```
.attr('value', this.Id)
```

to

```
.attr('value', this.Value)
```